# Unable to remove "Metadata file "...\bin\foo.dll" is not available" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dll, metadata

I am getting this issue for NewtonSoft Json dll. It's saying namespace 'Json' does not exist in namespace 'System.Runtime.Serialization'.

I had cleaned and built the code again. Also tried to add the dll into the bin folder but still no luck.

Why is this happening and how can I overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

There is both a System.Runtime.Serialization namespace and a NewtonSoft.Json.Serialization namespace and it sounds like it is using the former where you are expecting it to use the latter. Make sure you are referencing the right NewtonSoft namespace and/or are more explicit when declaring object of types from either namespace.